# Check whether a String can be parsed by a SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, regex, parsing, date, simpledateformat

As the question title states, how would it be possible to check whether a `String` can be parsed by a `SimpleDateFormat` before doing so? For example consider the following:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatterTest {

    DateFormatterTest() {
        String[] dateStrings = new String[]{"Tue Jan 27 15:12:04 GMT 2015", 
                                            "", 
                                            "Wed Jan 28 15:02:04 GMT 2015"};

        for(String dateString : dateStrings){
            Date date = null;
            try {
                //check whether dateString is parsable
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            java.lang.System.out.println(date + "");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DateFormatterTest();
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to check whether `dateString` is parsable, and if not leave the variable `date` as null? I know that I could just let the `try...catch` handle any parse exceptions. My other solution would be to write a regular expression to decide, but again I never quite trust that a regex will work in all cases.

The reason for this question is that I am reading in a large XML file using java DOM, and only some of the elements have an attached date attribute.

UPDATE: The reason that I am a little apprehensive about using the try catch to handle errors is the performance hit, as the XML file is rather large and it will be a common occurrence for the date variable to be missing. `try..catch`s are also bad for the readability of code.

Comment: I don't see why using a `try - catch` would be a particularly poor solution. It seems more like this is exactly the right choice for this situation.

Comment: I always thought that `Try...Catch` was quite slow and in this case the XML document is rather large. Also for the purpose of readability I would prefer it if my code did not jump about too much

Comment: I'd suggest not trying to optimize prematurely. If it becomes a problem you can still work around it with another structure, but generally the JVM does a lot of that already.

Comment: OK thanks, I will use the `try...catch` for now and wait to see if anybody has any other good solutions.

Comment: Re your update. There is a difference between "missing" and "cannot be parsed as a date". Checking for missing dates might be worthwhile. Both valid and invalid dates need to be parsed to see if they are valid, so adding a format check before the parse means checking each valid date twice.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, Thank you for the reply, checking for missing dates is how I have ended up doing it. I guess I was hoping to kill two birds with one stone by checking for invalid inputs (rare) and missing inputs (common) in one go. Maybe there is a way to override parse() to return null, rather than throw exception? That way, format would only be checked once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String text, ParsePosition pos)`.

Like this:

```
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatterTest {

    DateFormatterTest() {
        String[] dateStrings = new String[]{"Tue Jan 27 15:12:04 GMT 2015", 
                                            "", 
                                            "Wed Jan 28 15:02:04 GMT 2015"};

        for(String dateString : dateStrings){
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(dateString, new ParsePosition(0));
            java.lang.System.out.println(date + "");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DateFormatterTest();
    }
}
```

It returns `null` in case of error, as you want.

Comment: While certainly valid, wouldn't this be even more expensive in terms of processing time? `parse()` uses error checking internally, but it also has to update the `ParsePosition` to the line the error occured in if it does

Comment: @Dragondraikk, actually [DateFormat.parse(String source)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u40-dev/jdk/file/41fe61722ce9/src/share/classes/java/text/DateFormat.java) does exactly that: creates a `new ParsePosition(0)`. So it's like the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that checking for the ParseException is a valid solution. You can simply extract this to a method and obtain the functionality you want. Here is an example using your code.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatterTest {

    DateFormatterTest() {
        String[] dateStrings = new String[]{"Tue Jan 27 15:12:04 GMT 2015", 
                                        "", 
                                        "Wed Jan 28 15:02:04 GMT 2015"};

        for(String dateString : dateStrings){
            Date date = null;

            // call new method
            date = parseDate(dateString);

            java.lang.System.out.println(date + "");
        }
    }

    private Date parseDate(String dateString) {
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // ideally you would log this exception...
        }
        return date;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DateFormatterTest();
    }
}
```